# correct table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

is this table is correct? or I should put `unsignedBigInteger` for `tag_id` too? and remove `.->unsigned` and `index`?

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('post_tags');
}
```

Comment: Please provide more informations about your problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): it's unclear what you want and what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The table is not correct. The name, for starters. 
I guess it's an association table, between `posts` and `tags`. It should then be names `post_tag` (the plurals are dropped for an association).

Then, why the two different syntaxes ?

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
$table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

Either you use `unsignedInteger(...)`, either `integer(...)->unsigned()`. Not both. It's not wrong technically speaking, but it's not a good practice; chose a syntax and keep it.

Then : `unsignedBigInteger`, `unsignedInteger`, `unsignedSmallInteger`... What is important is the type of the primary key it makes reference to. If in your `tags` table, it's `bigInteger`, then you use `unsignedBigInteger`, and so on.

For the foreign key, you should use the following:

```
$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

There, your table should be correct.

Edit: no need for `timestamps()` in an association table, unless you want to keep tracking of changes. But it is more recommanded to have a log table. You can drop the line.

Comment: : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `blogapp`.`category_posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (S
QL: alter table `category_posts` add constraint `category_posts_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: @MariaQasim ``category_posts`` the name is incorrect. It should be ``category_post``. What is the type of id in ``posts.id`` ? If it's a bigIncrements or smallIncrements, it's normal you're getting this error, the type is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

/**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

```
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('post_tags');
}
```